# Conditional update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
UPDATE users_ SET equity=equity-100 WHERE account_id=1
```

The update has to be done only if the user has sufficient funds, i.e. equity is >= 100.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE users_
    SET equity = equity - 100
    WHERE account_id = 1 AND equity >= 100;
```

For extra protection, MySQL finally supports `check` constraints.  So in the most recent versions, you can do:

```
alter table users_ add constraints chk_users_equity
    check (equity >= 0);
```

This will not allow negative values.  Actually, if `equity` is an integer, then you can declare it to be unsigned and have the same effect.